# How to allow a secure remote desktop login, yet keep things convenient?

Tags: windows-7, security, remote-desktop

So I want to have RDP on my main desktop machine and while I did this countless times already, I always used just the hardest possible random passwords.
Which indeed works quite well on servers, as you don't have to log in locally.

But now I'm talking about my desktop machine here.
How could I secure it yet make it convenient to use it locally?
By locally I mean, I do lock my computer when I leave it around. I know that's not *secure*, but it's only against co-workers. And when I get back, I do have to unlock it with my password.

**One thing**, is that I know I could make an additional user and use that to log-in with Administrator rights, fair enough. But is there a "better way"? Like ... let's say for an example, I could use passwords on Linux, yet use my key files to log in. Secure yet convenient.
See what I mean?

Comment: Have you thought about using a smart card?

Comment: Maybe something like yubico?

Comment: @Darius - how durable a yubikey is? it looks like one of those fragile mini pendrives which also love to destroy USB ports.

Comment: @Shiki Unfortunately I haven't got a chance to test one. I only heard about their existence rather recently from a podcast called Security Now. After doing a quick search, it looks like they did a full podcast about Yubikey as per their transcript here: https://www.grc.com/sn/sn-143.pdf (which is on 8 May 2008) Audio version here: http://media.GRC.com/sn/SN-143.mp3 which discusses the technology, but I haven't read further about how durable they are. But I guess they can only be as durable as any other plastic USB devices..